# Not able to install "node_module"s

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am a node.js beginner..!!

I am trying to install node_modules but getting following error.
I am on Windows and using node.js v5.7.0
Also, getting the same error on Mac OS X.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First this is not an error but a warning saying you don't have a package.json file. This file could look like this for a beginning.

```
{
  "name": "project name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "main.js",
  "start": "node main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "colors": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

Check this to why using a [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json) file.

**Edit**

You can also run npm init (suggested by @Nicklas Ridewing)

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a `package.json` file before you run `npm install colors`

Just run

`npm init`

And follow the guide to create one :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `npm init` to setup you project `package.json`.

Use `npm install <package-name> --save` to save it to your dependencies.
Use `npm install <package-name> --save-dev` to save it to your development dependencies.

Those will be saved in to your package.json which will be your project main configuration file.